# Text format change with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have the below Ampscript to show the date as 'sent date' plus 14 days. The code works but when it renders into the email it kills the Arial (15) font and looks different to the rest of the email. How do i fix this. I selected all text and chose Arial font size 15. below is the code view and email display

**With code**

[image]

**Email display**

[image]

Comment: 1) Firstly try wrapping the second paragraph with SPAN tag as below... `<span style="font-family:arial !important;font-size:15px !important;">Our contractors will be in your area to carry out the upgrade any time after %%=v(@futureDate)=%% 2020.</span>` .......  2) If it does not work you may have to share the screenshot/code from the HTML editor section of your content block to find the issue.

Comment: Which content block are you using? The AMPscript you see in the editor should also be shown in Arial - it renders using the same font that you see in editor

Comment: Am using a text content block. I will insert the Span tag and revert.